# During first login to bugzilla Error:The username or password you entered is not valid

Tags: perl, bugzilla

I have setup the bugzilla installation on windows7.
I have installed:
1) Perl
2) My SQL

I ran chacksetup.pl...and given the admin user and password.Everything looks fine.

Now On main page of bugzilla when i try to login using admin account,then i am getting the error:The username or password you entered is not valid.

Even i checked the Profiles table of My Sql. The login name i am providing the correct.but when i see the password it looks like very encrypted and lengthy password..Is that the problem?

Please help me.I don't find any other way to understand the problem...

Thanks in advance and Happy new year.